# IDE stops responding to breakpoints when host header changes, even though it's same website

Tags: .net, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2013, ide

I have a website that can be reached through multiple host headers. The problem is that if the host header changes during debugging, then the ide stops responding to breakpoints. Oddly, if I detach the debugger and then manually attach it to the w3wp.exe process then it will begin stopping on the breakpoints again.

Is there any way I can get it to continue responding to breakpoints regardless of the host header without having to manually unattach and reattach the debugger after starting it every time?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I realized that IIS starts a new process for each host header so that's why it doesn't work because I'm not attached to the new w3wp.exe process that's being used after I redirect.

I think the best answer for me is to just change the startup url to use the host name for the customer I want to run the application as before starting it.